# Ctrl + C doesn't work correctly in a Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, copy-paste

I have an event on my DataGridView to copy data to clipboard, but my event doesn't detect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> pressing correctly (I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> about 15 times, to make this event detect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> pressing).

Here is the code:

```
    private void DataGridView_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.C))
        {
            DataObject d = DataGridView.GetClipboardContent();
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(d);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Why so?

Screenshot of what happens when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

[image]

Comment: When you say it *does not detect it*, are you basing that off the fact that you've got a break point somewhere and you're trying to debug it? Or are you running it without the debugger and it's *not detecting it?*

Comment: i run without debugger and it works for tenth time pressing

Comment: You should use e.Modifiers to check if the Ctrl key is pressed.

Comment: @Silvermind no, only Key_Up

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your screen-shot shows you detected the Ctrl key being released.  Not what you're after of course.

You can't do it with the KeyUp event, DataGridView already intercepts Ctrl+C for its own use.  And does the logical thing, copying the selected cell, column or row to the clipboard.  Do make sure it doesn't already do what you need it to do.

If you want to override it then you need to stay ahead of DGV.  That requires that you derive your own class from DataGridView and override the ProcessCmdKey() method.  Add a class to your project and make it look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyDataGridView : DataGridView {
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
        if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.C)) {
            // Do stuff
            //..
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

Comment: but why my DGV doesn't copy selected cells to clipboard if it has its own methods? or how can i allow my dgw to do this?

Comment: @Greag.Deay I've tried it and looks like the `Cell copy function` is enabled by default, why could you not see it work?

Comment: @KingKing `ClipboardCopyMode = EnableWithoutHeaderText` and it doens't copy to clipboard by ctrl+c. :(

Comment: @Greag.Deay not sure why it doesn't work for you BUT it works for me, although the default value is `EnableWithAutoHeaderText`

Answer (score 2):

If you put your breakpoint at the `if` case then you will be hitting this a lot with the wrong information. Unless you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd> at the exact same time.

I'm using this piece of code to capture the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (checking the [ModifierKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.modifierkeys.aspx)):

```
private void DataGridView_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.Key == Key.C &&
     (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == (ModifierKeys.Control))
 {
   DataObject d = DataGridView.GetClipboardContent();
   Clipboard.SetDataObject(d);
   e.Handled = true;
  }
}
```

Since it's Framework 2.0:

```
private void DataGridView_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.Key == Key.C && (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift)
 {
   DataObject d = DataGridView.GetClipboardContent();
   Clipboard.SetDataObject(d);
   e.Handled = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: No such property `e.Key`

Comment: On the 'KeyEventArgs e' you can find it.. Edited my question to reflect the entire method.

Comment: i can't find reference to windows.input. writing in framework 2.0 btw.

Comment: Ah okey.. You can check this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yazd4ct6(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @JonasW i'm using this  `(e.KeyCode == Keys.C && (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control)` and it works not every time again